# Why spring doesn't use JNDI to register and lookup beans by default?

Tags: java, spring, jndi

In the document of spring, It shows that its default way for bean management is using `DefaultListableBeanFactory.class`, which register beans into local list collection. Why does it not use JNDI?

Comment: Why should it use JNDI?

Comment: Then it would depend on a provided JNDI implementation.